# Java Запуск метода c определенной периодичностью

Tags: java, javafx

Имеется

```
public void FindDevice(ActionEvent actionEvent){   
XBeeNetwork myXBeeNetwork = myDevice.getNetwork();
myXBeeNetwork.startDiscoveryProcess();
}
```

В данный момент метод запускается по нажатию кнопки однократно, хотелось бы, чтобы после её нажатия     `XBeeNetwork myXBeeNetwork = myDevice.getNetwork(); myXBeeNetwork.startDiscoveryProcess();` запускались не однократно, а с интервалом в минуту, например.

Comment: Вы пытались пользоваться потоками и thread.sleep(10000) в цикле.

Comment: Или же вам не подходит такое решение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
    XBeeNetwork myXBeeNetwork = myDevice.getNetwork();
    myXBeeNetwork.startDiscoveryProcess();
}, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Comment: большое спасибо, подскажите, как остановить можно сей исполнитель или отредактировать интервал во время его работы?

Comment: @nikolay-rudavin метод `scheduleAtFixedRate` возвращает `Future`, которую можно отменить вызовом метода [cancel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel(boolean)).

Comment: Использовал executor.shutdown();

Comment: @nikolay-rudavin это остановит все запущенные задания.